# Facebook Registration Plugin on mobile gives API Error Code: 4202 "This dialog is not available on this device."

Tags: php, facebook, facebook-javascript-sdk, registration

I'm building a standalone website on Symfony 1.4/PHP that uses Facebook Registration Plugin for my user registration.

I'm using XBML Facebook Registration plugin and it works perfectly fine on a web browser.  But when I try to register for my site on a mobile touch screen device (android) browser, the registration form dialog shows up just fine with my autofilled facebook info, but when I click the register button, I get the following error:

> This dialog is not available on this device.  API Error Code: 4202  API Error Description: This dialog cannot be displayed on this device  Error Message: This method isn't supported for this display type

Here is my code:

```
<fb:registration 
    fields="[{'name':'name'}, {'name':'first_name'}, {'name':'last_name'}, {'name':'email'}, {'name':'gender'}, {'name':'birthday'}, {'name':'location'}]" 
    redirect-uri="<?php echo <REDIRECT URL>?>"
    display="touch"
    width="530"
    fb_only=true>
</fb:registration>
```

I've tried it with and without display="touch" as I read that might be an issue but it still gave the error.

Is Registration Plugin usable on Mobile Devices?  I suspect the issue is that when the registration button is clicked, there's a popup saying the following and the mobile browser doesn't know how to handle the popup?

> "You've just registered for XXX using your Facebook account. If you
>   didn't mean to do this, you can undo this below."

Any ideas? Thanks.

Comment: I've got this error too, is there a work-around?

Answer (score 0):

The problem is *Intentional* and has already been reported at *Facebook developers*:

https://developers.facebook.com/bugs/507406422635550?browse=search_511bd57f912f84e18364257

Comment: Whenever you have any suggestion, please add it as comment.